# Does the Linux Page Cache (Buffer Cache) only cache the files' clusters (pages) or does it also cache the Inodes (metadata)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cache, inode

The Linux-Kernel implements a Page Cache (often also called Buffer Cache) to speed up the file systems of the underlying storage devices.

Does the Page Cache only cache the pages or clusters of files or does it also cache the Inodes with the metadata?

Comment: see https://ncona.com/2018/05/linux-page-cache/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29870068/what-are-pagecache-dentries-inodes